# When importing Cartopy ImportError: DLL load failed while importing trace: The specified module could not be found

Tags: python, cartopy

I installed [Christoph Gohlke](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/)'s prebuilt wheel `Cartopy‑0.20.2‑cp39‑cp39‑win_amd64.whl` using pip in an active virtual environment. The environment is using Python 3.9.5. When trying to import Cartopy I get the error message below. This used to work before and now it no longer works and I can't figure out why. Does anyone know what the issue could be or what I'm missing?

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [4], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 import cartopy
      2 import cartopy.crs as ccrs
      3 import cartopy.io.img_tiles as cimgt

File ~\Downloads\GitHub\Project\venv\lib\site-packages\cartopy\__init__.py:110, in <module>
    105     pass
    108 # Commonly used sub-modules. Imported here to provide end-user
    109 # convenience.
--> 110 import cartopy.crs
    111 import cartopy.feature

File ~\Downloads\GitHub\Project\venv\lib\site-packages\cartopy\crs.py:27, in <module>
     24 from pyproj.exceptions import ProjError
     25 from shapely.prepared import prep
---> 27 import cartopy.trace
     30 try:
     31     # https://github.com/pyproj4/pyproj/pull/912
     32     from pyproj.crs import CustomConstructorCRS as _CRS

ImportError: DLL load failed while importing trace: The specified module could not be found.
```

Comment: Install [shapely](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#shapely) and [pyproj](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pyproj) from the same site.

Comment: I had the same shapely and pyproj versions installed via pip but when I used `--force-reinstall` it worked.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[As mentioned by cgohlke](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71557674/when-importing-cartopy-importerror-dll-load-failed-while-importing-trace-the-s#comment126485880_71557674) in the comments, installing the wheels of [shapely](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#shapely) and [pyproj](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#pyproj) from his website solves the issue.

If the libraries are already installed, use `--force-reinstall` to overwrite the existing installations.